# Olive oil lid sealed properly?

Tags: food-safety, oil, olive-oil

Is this olive oil lid sealed and safe to use even though the side looks bumpy? It looks sealed at the top but do tiny dents or slight bulges on the side of the lid matter? It was covered with plastic but I haven't opened the metal lid yet. (Above the 'R' and 'O' in POUR OUVRIR).

[image: Side of lid]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Olive oil bottles are not sealed for health reasons. I.e., olive oil is not processed through a sterile heat canning process.

The two primary reasons for sealing the bottles are to prevent leaks and to make them tamper proof.

The type of top in your picture is a 'Ropp Top'. It features a ring below the cap that will separate from the top when you open the bottle. This is a tamper-proof feature, as is the shrink-wrapped plastic applied over it. If the bottle had been tampered with, it would be evident and should not be purchased.

As long as your bottle has no leaks, it should be properly sealed and fine to use.

Comment: I'd still take it back to the store/shop for an exchange or refund

Comment: @Cynetta As a consumer, it's always your prerogative. Personally, i won't take back a product that has maintained its integrity. Too much loss in the chain that all of us have to pay for.

Comment: @Cindy thank you. I have been wondering why mayonnaise and oil does not have a seal the way tomato sauce does.

Answer (score -2):

It is impossible to tell if the lid is sealed to food safe standards by looking at the pic. Why take a chance? Take the bottle back to where you bought it and request an exchange or refund.